# Reaction roles in Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want my bot to send a message, and a person in the guild reacts with a specific emoji, then they get a role. Else assume false, and not get the role. I am having trouble understanding how reaction roles work in Discord.js, so I would like a simple explanation on them.

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (message.content === 'sky exclusive') {
    message.channel.send('react to this message with a smiley face for an exclusive role!');
    message.react('');
    if(message.react === '') {
    guild.roles.create({
  data: {
    name: 'rolered',
    color: 'RED',
  },
  reason: 'we needed a role for rolered',
})
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
  }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<Message>.react` is a function. You may be looking for a reaction collector, or reaction event.

```js
//Reaction collector
let collector = <Message>.createReactionCollector(r => r.emoji.name === '');
collector.on('collect', async (reaction, user) => {
let guild = reaction.message.guild;
let member = guild.member(user);
member.roles.add('someRole')
})
```

You may need to tweak this, I didn’t get to test it.